# 500 Error on PHP script used by AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem with a script accessed via AJAX on my site.
I've narrowed it down to the include file itself as it springs the 500 even when loaded independently of the AJAX stuff.

The code in the include throwing the 500 is as follows:

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'sac-active-wp/wp-blog-header.php');

$pagetitle = $_POST;
$value = array_shift($pagetitle);

$thequery = 'title_li=&parent='.$value.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=ASC'; 
$display = wp_list_pages($thequery);
echo $display;

?>
```

The code takes an ID from AJAX POST and builds a Wordpress nav using said ID.

Anyone have any ideas why this is 500ing on me? I'm unable to access server logs due to permissions in the company here unfortunately, but I can confirm it works on my XAMPP localhost, just not on the live server :(

Thanks in advance guys,
Graham

Comment: What is exact output of AJAX resopnse

Comment: $pagetitle = $_POST; Is it correct?

Comment: Presumably your include fails and the 500 is due to a call to undefined function `wp_list_pages`. Try to require wp-blog-header.php` relatively based on your script location or using constants such as `require_once WP_HOME . '/wp-blog-header.php';`. Also beware of injection where you append `$value`.

Comment: No output, all I'm getting is a Firebug console 500 error:
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - mysitesurl.com/sac-active-wp/buildnav.php"

mysiteurl omitted for security! Thanks

Comment: Get access to your server logs. You can't develop without it. Period. If they don't trust their developers, then they need to rethink production deployments. It could be any number of things. It's like trying to shoot a bullseye in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is not returning the same location on the webserver as on your XAMPP,

You should check if it goes to the right directory by running:

```
<?php 
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, turned out it was the DOCUMENT ROOT serving an incorrect path! Fixed now, greatly appreciated :)